# Passando string via socket em Python

Tags: python, socket

Estou tentando desenvolver um projeto de rede aqui em minha empresa e preciso passar algumas strings de um computador para o outro. Optei por fazer isso via socket.

Eu estou fazendo testes com dois scripts, `server.py` e `client.py`. O problema é que a mensagem enviada pelo `client.py` sempre está em um formato de `b'minhamensagem'`. Como faço para limpar isso?

Arquivo `server.py`:

```
import socket
def server(host = 'localhost', port=5000):
    data_payload = 5048 #The maximum amount of data to be received at once
    # Create a TCP socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Enable reuse address/port 
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    # Bind the socket to the port
    server_address = (host, port)
    print ("Starting up echo server  on %s port %s" % server_address)
    sock.bind(server_address)
    # Listen to clients, argument specifies the max no. of queued connections
    sock.listen(5) 
    i = 0
    while True: 
        print ("Waiting to receive message from client")
        client, address = sock.accept() 
        data = client.recv(data_payload) 
        if data:
            print(data)
            input("PAUSE")
            print ("Data: %s" %data)
            client.send(data)
            print ("sent %s bytes back to %s" % (data, address))
            # end connection
            client.close()
            i+=1
            if i>=3: break           
server()
```

Arquivo `client.py`:

```
import socket
def client(host = 'localhost', port=5000): 
 # Create a TCP/IP socket 
 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
 # Connect the socket to the server 
 server_address = (host, port) 
 print ("Connecting to %s port %s" % server_address) 
 sock.connect(server_address) 
 # Send data 
 try: 
     # Send data 
     message = "Teste de conexao remota CentralBR" 
     print ("Sending %s" % message) 
     sock.sendall(message.encode("utf-8")) 
     # Look for the response 
     amount_received = 0 
     amount_expected = len(message) 
     while amount_received < amount_expected: 
         data = sock.recv(64) 
         amount_received += len(data) 
         print ("Received: %s" % data) 
 except socket.error as e: 
     print ("Socket error: %s" %str(e)) 
 except Exception as e: 
     print ("Other exception: %s" %str(e)) 
 finally: 
     print ("Closing connection to the server") 
     sock.close() 

client()
```

Neste caso, meu `server.py` recebe `b'Teste de conexao remota CentralBR'`

Answer (score 0):

O que está vendo de estranho nessas `strings` é **a representação de Bytes Objects no Python**. O Python tem essa representação com strings e está bem explicado [neste post em inglês no próprio Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal).

[A documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) também pode ajudar a entender como o Python representa esses bytes usando apenas caracteres `ASCII`.

Para converter os bytes para string (em Python 3) você pode usar o método `decode`:

```
byte_string = b'my byte string'
# "encoding" pode ter outros valores para conversão, como 'latin-1'. Depende do que quer converter.
decoded_string = byte_string.decode(encoding="utf-8")
print(decoded_string)
```

A saída do código acima seria:

```
my_byte_string
```